# Content of data frame into list with specific form

Tags: r, list, transformation

I am looking for a specific transformation of data into a list format. What I want is best explained with example data:

```
library(dplyr)    

data <- as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(1:4, 10, 1, byrow=T), matrix(2:6, 10, 1, byrow=T), matrix(2:7, 10, 1, byrow=T))) %>%
dplyr::group_by(V1) %>%
dplyr::arrange(.by_group = TRUE)

data # For emphasis "grouped by" V1

# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   V1 [4]
  V1    V2    V3
<int> <int> <int>
  1     2     2
  1     6     6
  1     5     4

  2     3     3
  2     2     7
  2     6     5

  3     4     4
  3     3     2

  4     5     5
  4     4     3
```

The aim is to obtain a list of the following format in which V1 serves as split (or group)-variable and column V2 and V3 become separated sub-lists of V1:

```
str(list(list(c(2,6,5),c(2,6,4)), list(c(3,2,6),c(3,7,5)),list(c(4,3),c(4,2)), list(c(5,4),c(5,3))))

List of 4
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : num [1:3] 2 6 5
  ..$ : num [1:3] 2 6 4
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : num [1:3] 3 2 6
  ..$ : num [1:3] 3 7 5
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : num [1:2] 4 3
  ..$ : num [1:2] 4 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : num [1:2] 5 4
  ..$ : num [1:2] 5 3
```

As you can see, I get as many lists as I have distinct values in V1. In each of those lists the entries of the columns V2 and V3 belonging to a specific value of V1 are defined as separate lists.

Now what I am looking for is a specific "formula" to do this for me. I've tried my luck with various combinations of lapply/mapply/split, but so far unsuccessful I ended up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `split` the 'data', convert to `list`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
lst <- split(data[-1], data[1]) %>%
                   map(as.list)
```

---

Or another approach is to `nest`, extract the `.$data` and convert to `list`

```
lst2 <- data %>% 
           nest(V2, V3) %>%
          .$data %>%
           map(as.list)
str(lst2)
#List of 4
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ V2: int [1:3] 2 6 5
#  ..$ V3: int [1:3] 2 6 4
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ V2: int [1:3] 3 2 6
#  ..$ V3: int [1:3] 3 7 5
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ V2: int [1:2] 4 3
#  ..$ V3: int [1:2] 4 2
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ V2: int [1:2] 5 4
#  ..$ V3: int [1:2] 5 3
```

Also, the names 'V2', 'V3' can be removed with `unname`

```
lst2 %>%
    map(unname) %>%
    str
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, the first suggestion is not what I am looking for. Note the difference between your suggestion

`str(list(list(c(2,6,5)),list(c(2,6,4))))`

and my desired form

`str(list(list(c(2,6,5),c(2,6,4))))`

.
The second suggestion has a similar problem.

Comment: @MaHo Both of the methods gives the same structure you showed (except the class being integer which depends on the initial data) based on your example

Comment: Ah, I forgot to str() it - you're right! Thank you so much!